# replication between SQL Server and MySQL server

Tags: replication

I want to setup replication between SQL Server and MySQL, in which SQL Server is the primary database server and MySQL is the slave server (on linux).

Is there a way to setup such scenario? Help me .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replication between SQL Server and MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902984/replication-between-sql-server-and-mysql)

Answer (score 9):

My answer might be coming too late, but still for future reference ...
You can use one of the heterogeneous replication solutions like SymmetricDS: http://www.symmetricds.org/. It can replicate data between any SQL database to any SQL database, altough the overhead is higher than using a native replication solution.

Answer (score 8):

of course you can replicate MSSQL database to MYSQL

1. By using Linked Server in MSSQL.
   for that you need to download ODBC drivers. and you can further search regarding how to create Linked server on SQL SERVER.
   This option is very easy and Totally free. You can use OPEN QUERY FOR THIS.
2. By using SSIS Packages.
   for that you need the Business Intelligence service of SQL SERVER. you can create SSIS Packages on Visual Studio and run them for replication.

Comment: I have worked on this very deeply and to be honest the easiest method is to work with linked server in mssql. rather than working on ssis packages which is quite hard to understand at first.

Answer (score 2):

No. At least not without doing a lot of dirty, bad things. MSSQL and MySQL speak different replication protocols, so you won't be able to set it up natively (which is the way you'd want to handle it).  At best, you could hack together some sort of proxy that forwards insert/update/delete/create/alter, etc. queries from one to the other.  This is a terrible idea as they don't speak the same SQL except in the most common case.  Even database dumps which wouldn't really be replication are generally incompatible between vendors.

Don't do it. If you must use different OSes on your servers, standardize the database to something that runs on both.

Answer (score 0):

These two databases are from two different vendors. While I cannot say for sure, it is unlikely Microsoft has any interest in allowing replication to a different vendor's database server.

I work with Informix and MySQL. Both those databases have commands that dump the entire database to an ascii file format. You would need to see how that is done on MS SQL Server; ftp the dump to the server hosting the MySQL server; and then convert the dump into something MySQL can import.