# Replication between SQL Server and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, odbc, replication

I am trying to set up replication between SQL Server 2008 and MYSQL. I have installed a MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver on the MySQL server. Initially I was trying to just set up a linked server between the two databases which is working fine.

However now I am trying to set up replication in SSMS. I have created a simple publication but I am having problems setting up the subscriber. The only heterogeneous datasources it seems I can set up under Oracle and IBM. I do however think that I should be able to use the ODBC driver installed and replicate to the MySQL database.

Any ideas?! Thanking anyone in advance

Comment: We need more details, please - what have you tried and why doesn't it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151149.aspx) is very clear that only Oracle and DB2 are supported in any way, and only when using OLE DB, not ODBC. Therefore, trying to set up replication to MySQL using ODBC is almost certainly a waste of time.

Having said that, native SQL Server replication is not the only way to copy data between databases, and if you can give some more information about your requirements then someone may have an alternative solution.

For example, if your goal is some form of reporting or data warehousing then you can look into the many ETL tools that are available and work with many different databases. (I'm assuming your goal is not redundancy or availability, because you're using two different platforms.)