# Maintain two tables in sync using SSIS. Is it a good idea or an overkill?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ssis

We are currently maintaining 2 database tables in sync by using a simple SQL statement:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE A;
GO
INSERT INTO A SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(....)
```

So far, it has been working pretty well (about 25'000 lines copied at each run), but I think that it has the following 2 caveats:

- It definitely lacks logging
- Performances are poor because the second table is a mySQL table accessed via an OpenQuery

As we are currently reviewing this process, I was considering using an SSIS package to maintain the tables in sync.

Do you think it is worth it? Or is it an overkill? Can someone share their experience sychronizing mySQL table with MS SQL table?

Comment: Are you snapshotting or syncing?  What fraction of rows change?

Comment: @Anon I'm not quite sure I get your first question. Could you please be more specific? About 200 rows change (additions and deletions) per month. About 100 rows are updated per day.

Comment: It's a question of what your goal is.  Do you want to tell your users: "This is a snapshot of the source table as of time x.  The next scheduled update will happen at time y.", or "These tables are synchronized with no more than z delay".

Comment: @Anon Due to external constraints (performance of the FIM engine actually consuming the data provided), we are doing a daily snapshot. However, our goal is to guaranty that data are not more than n hours old (with n being the smallest as possible). But as a first step, let's assume it only needs to get refreshed twice a day.

Comment: There are heterogeneous replication systems - see the answer to this question for an open source example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904447/replication-between-sql-server-and-mysql-server